# Inserting data from one table to another without duplication in access-VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to insert data from a table `WorkTableA` to another table `TableA`, without duplicating the data (i.e. do not insert into `WorkTableA` if the customer name already `exists`).

Is there a way of doing it through VBA code. 
The field name and their properties in both tables are identical.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is  an `INSERT INTO` statement

```
INSERT INTO WorkTableA
 ( CustomerName, Col2, Col3...) 
SELECT CustomerName, Col2, Col3
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN WaorkTableA ON TableA.CustomerName = WORKTABLEA.CustomerName
WHERE WorkTableA.CustomerName IS NULL
```

Something like this might work. 
The `SELECT` part of the statement will select only the ones that DO NOT `EXIST` in `WorkTableA`